# How to pass a float array and a float as parameters to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to send 2 parameters (a float and an array of floats) to a function in C.

**I'm getting this error:**

```
test.c:10:1: error: conflicting types for ‘result’
 result(float *array, float number){
 ^
test.c:10:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
test.c:7:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘result’ was here
     result(array, number);
```

**My code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    float array[3] = {1.5, 2.6, 3.7};
    float number = 2.3;
    result(array, number);
}

result(float *array, float number)
{
    printf("number: %f\n", number);
    printf("array 1: %f\n", array[1]);
}
```

I'm new to C and know that in other languages this would work, so any help on what to do here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Put the `result` definition above `main`. Or declare its prototype there. In C, declarations must come before they are first used. Otherwise the compiler will assume some defaults which are often not what you want (e.g. assumes parameters are integers).

Comment: Note that pre-standard C and C90 were sloppy about allowing functions to be called without a declaration or definition before the use, whereas C99 and C11 do not allow that. However, because of the default promotion rules that convert a `float` to a `double` in a function parameter list would have caused trouble in a single file even in C90.  (Pre-standard C would not have allowed the prototype notation in the function definition, so there wouldn't have been a problem there — but the code would have been different, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access functions declared after `main` without a prototype. Rewrite your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int result(float *, float);

int main()
{
    /* ... */
}

int result(float *array, float number)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code is this:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void result(float array[3], float number){
    printf("number: %f\n", number);
    printf("array 1: %f\n", array[1]);
}

main(){
    float array[3] = {1.5, 2.6, 3.7};
    float number = 2.3;
    result(array, number);
}
```

`